# Subsetting numeric values by a separate categorical value

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I have a dataset on healthcare premiums in market areas and I'm trying to query the lowest value by market area and state. Here is the dataset:

```
state  area  premium
AK     AK1   500
AK     AK1   550
AK     AK2   600
AK     AK2   540 
AL     AL1   500
AL     AL1   400
AL     AL2   400
AL     AL2   500
```

I am trying to get:

```
state  area  premium
AK     AK1   500
AK     AK2   540
AL     AL1   400
AL     AL2   400
```

Answer (score 2):

You can perform an SQL query similar to this:

```
odbc load, exec("SELECT state,area,min(premium) FROM myschema.MyTable GROUP BY 
state,area;") dsn(MyDatasource)
```

Or:

```
collapse (min) premium by(state,area)
```

Comment: Nice answer, but the by option for collapse should not contain a comma.

Comment: Also `bysort state area (premium) : keep if _n == 1`.